# Retrieving Full Computer Name

Tags: c#, windows

I am developing a Windows Application by using C#. I have a form in which I dragged one textBox and one button control. I want to retrieve the user Full Computer Name in the textBox by clicking the button.I wrote some codes for that as..........

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)            
{                
    string name = System.Environment.MachineName;                
    textBox1.Text = name[0].ToString();            
}
```

By clicking the button, it retrieves only the first letter(eg: D for Donald-PC) of the Computer Name by which it starts but I want to retrieve the Full Name(eg: Donald-PC). Please someone help if I have make any change in my codes.Thanks

Comment: `name[0]` explicitly gets the first character of the name.

Comment: I see 3 "not constructive" close votes! Do people just blindly select the same close vote reason as the last voter? Something is wrong with close voting at the moment here on SO. It needs attention!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes I do that, saves thinking about it too long. Too often Qs fit multiple close reasons anyway. Maybe you should bring that up on meta.

Answer (score 4):

Just output the full name, not just the 0 index:

```
textBox1.Text = name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the first character of `System.Environment.MachineName`. You need to do this:

```
textBox1.Text = System.Environment.MachineName;
```

As an aside, `textBox1` for a control name is really lousy.

Answer (score 0):

You are using char index of array, drop [0] and use just name.